# Alert the user that other datatypes (eg string) was inserted without crashing

Tags: c#, .net

This is the interface for calculation. The interface has two methods `calculateArea` and `totalCost`.

```
public interface ICalculation {
  int calculateArea();int totalCost()
}
```

Here I'm inheriting the interface class. The variables are litre, length, height.

```
public class Calculation : ICalculation {
    public int litre;
    public int length;
    public int height;
    public Calculation() {
        litre= 0;length = 0;height = 0;
    }

    public Calculation(int litre2, int lenght2, int height2) {
         this.litre = litre2;
         this.length = lenght2;
         this.height = height2;
    }

    public int calculateArea() {
        return length * height;
    } 

    public int totalCost() {
        return calculateArea()* litre;
    }
```

Testing the program to see the output.
Create a new object calculation and then prompt the user to fill in the litre, length and height.  Calculate the area and total cost after getting the values.

```
class Tester {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
       Calculation c = new Calculation();

       try{ 
            Console.WriteLine("How much litre?");
            c.litre = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What is the lenght");
            c.length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What is the height");
            c.height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("The Total area " + c.calculateArea());
            Console.WriteLine("The Total cost for the project is " + c.totalCost());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }       
        catch(FormatException ){
            Console.WriteLine("{0}is not an integer, try again!");
            // Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want a user to ONLY be able to enter int values from the console namely; the litre, length and height. Alert the user that other datatypes(e.g. string) was inserted and prompt them to try again. The problem is the code crashes as soon a non-int value is inserted at any of the given values. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I would say validate using a while loop.

```
int i;
while (true)
{
  var line = Console.ReadLine();
  if (int.TryParse(line, out i))
    break;
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
}
```

Comment: A detailed explanation is highly appreciated?

Comment: The use of `int.TryParse` is to avoid exceptions occurring during an invalid cast. It will return `true` if the parsing is successful and `false` if not. The `break` statement will break you out of the loop. The use on @Mark Fro 's answer states that while the user input is not a valid integer, he will continue to show `"Invalid number"` but if it valid, he will break out of the loop to continue with the program processes. There are different ways of implementing this but the main helper is the `int.TryParse`.

Comment: ok where and how can i modify the code to validate this? im using an object c to read values retrieved from the console..

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of Mark answer.

```
public  static int ReadFromConsole()
{
    int i;
    while (true)
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(line, out i)) break;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number.");
    }

    return i;
}
```

then you can just call it like this.

```
Console.WriteLine("How much litre?");
c.litre = ReadFromConsole();
Console.WriteLine("What is the lenght");
c.length = ReadFromConsole();
Console.WriteLine("What is the height");
c.height = ReadFromConsole();
```